# C# Error in constructor of a class

Tags: c#

I try to randomize the values if they are not changed, but it won't let me use the randomizer in the constructor and it gives an error when I use my other function.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Randomizer {
    class Apartment {
        public int height;
        public int bas;
        public int hasPent;
        public Apartment(int b = 100, int h = 100, int p = 100) {
            height = h;
            bas = b;
            hasPent = p;
            public Room[,,] rooms = new Room[bas, bas, height];
            finCon(bas, height, hasPent, rooms);
        }
    
        void finCon(int b, int h, int p, Room[,,] ro) {
            Random r = new Random();
            if (b==100) {
                b = r.Next(2,4);
            }
            if (h==100) {
                h = r.Next(4,15);
            }
            if (p==100) {
                p = r.Next(0,20);
            }
        }
    }
    class Room {
        int some = 37;
    }
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Apartment ap = new Apartment();
            ap.finCon(ap.bas,ap.height,ap.hasPent,ap.rooms);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}",ap.bas,ap.height);
            }
        }
    }
```

Errors:

> (1:1) A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods
>
> (16:25) } expected
>
> (18:13) Method must have a return type
>
> (18:23) Identifier expected
>
> (18:31) Identifier expected
>
> (18:40) Identifier expected
>
> (18:47) Identifier expected
>
> (21:9) A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods
>
> (21:47) Identifier expected
>
> (21:48) Identifier expected
>
> (21:51) Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
>
> (22:28) Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
>
> (33:5) Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
>
> (46:1) Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected

Comment: You should include the error details in your question.

Comment: If you're getting errors, it is **always** helpful to include them in your post. Don't leave us guessing and searching your code for issues.

Comment: You can't put `public Room[,,] rooms = new Room[bas, bas, height];` inside the constructor. You need `public Room[,,] rooms;` with the rest of the fields (e.g., directly below `public int hasPent;`), then in the constructor you want `rooms = new Room[bas, bas, height];` after the assignment to `bas` and `height`.

Comment: Start over from scratch and build your program one line at a time, making sure it builds between each step.  When your program stops building, figure out why the line you just added is breaking it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made it compile:

```
namespace Randomizer
{
    public class Apartment
    {
        public int height;
        public int bas;
        public int hasPent;
        public Room[,,] rooms;

        public Apartment(int b = 100, int h = 100, int p = 100)
        {
            height = h;
            bas = b;
            hasPent = p;
            rooms = new Room[bas, bas, height];
            finCon(bas, height, hasPent, rooms);
        }

        public void finCon(int b, int h, int p, Room[,,] ro)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            if (b == 100)
            {
                b = r.Next(2, 4);
            }
            if (h == 100)
            {
                h = r.Next(4, 15);
            }
            if (p == 100)
            {
                p = r.Next(0, 20);
            }
        }
    }

    public class Room
    {
        int some = 37;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Apartment ap = new Apartment();
            ap.finCon(ap.bas, ap.height, ap.hasPent, ap.rooms);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}", ap.bas, ap.height);
        }
    }
}
```

Your problem is trying to declare a `property` inside the constructor (you can't do it). I've made all classes public too.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I also changed it so it is just finCon() and uses this.thevariablename